Not getting css on image with nodeamiler
Hello people as the title suggests, I am trying to send HTML with an image via nodemailer , everything looks fine when I test it in the browser but it seems like the CSS for the image I ignored.
I tried:
-inline styles
-removing css functions
on all other elments css works fine
dose anyone hav any idea ?


        *:before,
        *:after {
            box-sizing: inherit;
        }

        body,
        h1,
        h2,
        h3,
        h4,
        h5,
        h6,
        p,
        ol,
        ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        ol,
        ul {
            list-style: none;
        }

        /* body {
            height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        } */

        .container {
            margin-top: 3%;
            padding: auto 50%;
            position: relative;
            background-color: rgb(252, 235, 211);
            width: 30%;
            height: 30%;
        }

        .text-box {
            height: 20em;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .img {
            width: auto;
            height: 15%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 92.5%;
            right: 0;
        }
        p {
            padding: 5%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <section class="container">
                    <a href="https://www.zivmakesbeats.com"
                        ><img class="img" src="cid:z.m.b-01.png" 
                    /></a>

                    <div class="text-box">
                        <p>MESSAGE dfsdf sdfsdf sf sdf</p>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

backend
serSchema.statics.contact = async function (req, res, next) {
const replacedHtml = await replaceHtml(templateHtml, [
    ['MESSAGE', req.body.massage],
])
try {
    const toAdminOptions = {
        from: `${req.name} <${req.email}>`,
        to: ' zivmakesbeats@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Contact-us',
        html: replacedHtml,
        attachments: [
            {
                filename: 'z.m.b-01.png',
                path: './public/z.m.b-01.png',
                cid: 'z.m.b-01.png',
            },
        ],
    }

    const sent = await transporter.sendMail(toAdminOptions)
    res.json(sent)
} catch (err) {
    next(err)
}

}
